# Standing spherical wave solution

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, potential, reflection, resonance

Let's say we have a spherically symmetric light wave $u(r,t,\theta,\phi)= u(r,t)$ that satisfies the following wave equation with spherically symmetric potential $V(r)=2/r^2$ (also set $c= 1$ so $\omega = k$):

$$\ddot{u} - u'' + \frac{2u}{r^2} = 0 $$

Where $\ddot{u} \equiv \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$ and $u'' \equiv \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}$. The solution to this equation is of the form:

$$u(r,t) =  \sum_k \cos kt \left\{ A_k \left( \frac{ \cos k r}{kr} + \sin k r \right)+ B_k \left( \frac{\sin k r}{k r} - \cos k r \right) \right\}  $$

I need some help understanding this solution. Specifically the following points:

1) First it seems that at $r=0$ the potential becomes infinity, so can we discard the $A$ modes? (The $\frac{\cos{kr}}{kr}$ term blows up at 0).

2) Is this a standing wave solution? It looks like it is because there is no explicit $\cos\left(\omega t \pm kr\right)$ for example.

3) Given that the solution is not a plane wave moving in a definite direction, we would expect this solution to consist of both waves moving toward high $r$ (transmitted) and towards low $r$ (reflected). I am interested in the question of the relative amplitude of the reflected and transmitted waves (ratio of reflection and transmission coefficients) for a specific value of $r$. Is this a well defined question assuming this standing wave? Or are the coefficients everywhere $R=T=.5$? How can I identify the components that are moving toward high $r$ and towards low $r$?

EDIT: Even if you don't know the answer to the question or don't feel like answering, if could point me to some relevant literature that would be great. I don't even know where to start looking for this kind of problem.

Comment: What physical quantity is $u$?

Comment: It is suppose to be the amplitude of the light wave. More specifically, this equation comes about if you write down the Euler-Lagrange equation for a massless scalar field $u$ and some potential.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: I am unclear actually, I want to say $u\left(0,t\right) = 0$ is one of them, but not sure (otherwise energy blows up).

Comment: The precise nature of your solution depends on the boundary conditions. In addition, the sum of standing waves can be a traveling wave.